# How does StorageManager.mountObb work

Tags: java, android

After mounting an OBB, I'm able to access it perfectly.  I've noticed that I can delete the obb file and I can still access everything.  I can even restart the app and access it's contents.  If I restart the device, it behaves as expected, and it seems unmounted.

So the question is, how can I still read the contents of the obb after deleting it and how can I even delete it in first place?  Maybe the storagemanager copies it internally somewhere?  This is a large obb, almost 2 gb, I can't imagine that it's all in memory.

Comment: From the docs: _However, due to their size, they're most likely stored in a shared storage pool accessible from all programs._ It also makes a mention that the OBB _will remain mounted for as long as the StorageManager reference is held by the application_. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html

Comment: They are referring to where the obb files are stored there.  Not really how it works.  If you delete the obb from the location that they reference while your app is running after mounting it, your app does not miss a beat, regardless of size.

Answer (score 0):

OBB files are downloaded to the device shared storage. Typically /storage/sdcard/Android/obb/package name, but paths may vary depending on available storage (internal/external) and device API. You can get a list of possible places where OBB files can reside by calling Context.getObbDirs(). To get the default directory, call Context.getObbDir() (usually on internal storage if there are both internal and external storages)

They can be mounted (think of it as read-only hard linking the contents of the OBB file to a directory in the file system, typically in /mnt/obb/someserial) or unpacked to another location in the shared storage. The system does not keep multiple copies of the originally downloaded OBB files (will use either internal obbDir or external obbDir (that can be changed by the user by moving an app to/from sdcard if app supports it)

When you delete the source OBB file, because it was already mounted, think of it as deleting only the hard link in an ext4 file system.
The inodes (the actual data) will stay on disk until all the references (hard links) are deleted. Because the mounted OBB (/mnt/obb/random sequence) is still referencing the same inodes that belonged to the source OBB file, the inodes are still on disk and accessible to your app until you unmount the OBB file (which happens when you restart the device).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

To summarize, OBB files are on disk, only one copy (unless explicitly unpacked by the app or duplicated by the user), but the actual data will not be deleted from disk until all the references are removed.